# How to inherit a thread class with infinite loop

Tags: python, multithreading, inheritance

Okay, suppose I've got a working class that inherits Thread:

```
from threading import Thread
import time    

class DoStuffClass(Thread):

    def __init__(self, queue):
        self. queue = queue
        self.isstart = False

    def startthread(self, isstart):
        self.isstart = isstart
        if isstart:
            Thread.__init__(self)
        else:
            print 'Thread not started!'

    def run(self):
        while self.isstart:
            time.sleep(1)
            if self.queue.full():
                y = self.queue.get()    #y goes nowhere, it's just to free up the queue
            self.queue.put('stream data')
```

I've tried calling it in another file and it's working successfully:

```
from Queue import Queue
import dostuff

q = Queue(maxsize=1)
letsdostuff= dostuff.DoStuffClass()

letsdostuff.startthread(True)

letsdostuff.start()
val = ''
i=0
while (True):
    val = q.get()
    print "Outputting: %s" % val
```

Right now, I can get the value of the class output thru the queue.

My question: Suppose I want to create another class (ProcessStuff) that inherits the DoStuffClass so that I can grab the output of DoStuffClass through a queue object (or any other method), process it, and pass it to ProcessStuff's queue so that codes calling the ProcessStuff can get its value through queuing. How do I do that?

Comment: Also, please see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875398/python-threads-always-have-x-active-threads-when-iterating-over-n-tasks#comment40494089_25875398) I made on another question about multithreading. You may be better off using the `multiprocessing` module instead of `threading`, if your threads are doing CPU-bound operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sound like you don't really want `ProcessStuff` to inherit from `DoStuffClass`, instead you want `ProcessStuff` to consume from the `DoStuffClass` queue internally. So rather than use inheritance, just have `ProcessStuff` keep a reference to a `DoStuffClass` instance internally, along with an internal `Queue` object to get the values that `DoStuffClass` produces:

```
class ProcessStuff(Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super(ProcessStuff, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self._do_queue = Queue()  # internal Queue for DoStuffClass
        self._do_stuff = dostuff.DoStuffClass(self._do_queue)

    def run(self):
        self._do_stuff.startthread(True)
        self._do_stuff.start()
        while True:
            val = self._do_queue.get()  # Grab value from DoStuffClass
            # process it
            processed_val = "processed {}".format(val)
            self.queue.put(processed_val)

q = Queue(maxsize=1)
letsprocessstuff = ProcessStuff(q)

letsprocessstuff.start()
while (True):
    val = q.get()
    print "Outputting: %s" % val
```

Output:

```
Outputting: processed stream data
Outputting: processed stream data
Outputting: processed stream data
Outputting: processed stream data
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I require - couldn't find the exact words when asking for it! I see it uses super() - if I replace it with Thread.__init__(self) it works just as fine.